# What do the different dots next to the review queues mean?

Tags: support, review-queues, top-bar

When I click on the "review" dropdown, I notice the dots next to each queue. I also notice that they can be different colors: light, dark, and not present.

The absence of a dot means that the queue is empty, but what does the dark dot mean? Are there other colors I don't know about?